# Appending shapes based on assigned class

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to add shapes based on the assigned class in the data set and then selectively append either a circle or rectangle or whatever.

I've tried adding the class and selectAll but can't get it to work.   The attached fiddle is based on svg:g group suggestion by FernOfTheAndes: http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/HVkyL/6/

Any ideas?

```
.attr("class", function (d) { return d.shape ? "rectangle" : "circle"; });

group.selectAll(".rectangle");   or  group.selectAll(".circle");
```

Comment: How are you appending those shapes?

Comment: group = vis.selectAll(".rectangle").data(datar);
               
                
        gEnter = group.enter()
             .append("g")
             .attr("class", "instant")
            
             
        gEnter.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "rectband");

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Aren't you already doing what you want to do, i.e. select by class and append elements accordingly?

Comment: I'm trying to select based on class assigned to group.  This modified fiddle doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/fN46y/  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any classes assigned and elements selected in this fiddle. Where exactly is that code?

Comment: sorry wrong fiddle above: http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/fN46y/2/  I expected it to draw on 3 rectangles as one item is in the circle class and now the transitions don't work properly!

Comment: this version transitions properly but still doesn't select based on class.  http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/fN46y/4/

Comment: You need to actually do the selection based on class instead of using `gEnter`. http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/fN46y/4/

Comment: Thanks -did you amend anything in the fiddle you attached?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link -- http://jsfiddle.net/fN46y/5/

Comment: I now see 4 red circles!  The code also has an error that I should have corrected to:  .attr("class", function (d) { return d.shape? "rectangle" : "circle"; }).  When this is changed we are back to 4 blue rectangles!

Comment: That should be closer to what you want, no?

Comment: did you attach another fiddle?

Comment: The last fiddle I posted...

Comment: I can't see any changes.  Still all re circles!

Comment: Yes... that's what I posted.

Comment: I'm trying to apply this method used in timeline proof of concept to my situation
https://gist.github.com/rengel-de/5603464   lines 211 to 237.  Your suggestion doesn't seem to make use of the class assignment 
which should be   .attr("class", function (d) { return d.shape ? "rectangle" : "circle"; })   (not d.instant my mistake)

Comment: I'm selecting based on the class assignment, as your question suggests. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Spotted an error with my code.  Shape should be true or false.  http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/fN46y/6/   Updated with suggestions above but still doesn't produce rect and circles

Comment: Last hurdle!  Get the transition working http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/fN46y/7/   Changed "true" to true and it worked accept the exit statement isn't right as duplicates appear.  Any ideas?  Thanks for your patients.

Comment: Should work fine if you handle the exit first http://jsfiddle.net/fN46y/8/

Comment: Just not there yet.  When the name radio button is selected the circles and rectangles double up for some reason?

Comment: This gets the job done: group = vis.selectAll(".rectangle, .circle") http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/fN46y/13/   Thanks again.

Comment: Do you know why I can't accept one of these answers?  I can't see the empty tick!

Comment: These are just comments. There are no answers, but feel free to post what you did.

Comment: I've just noticed that the colours get more intense every time a radio button is selected and the text fades out.  I've tried moving the fill statement about but that doesn't work.  Any thoughts on this? http://jsfiddle.net/sjp700/fN46y/13/